# Mass Transit sends the message again. While the first message is still processing

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

MassTransit V 6.3.2 I have consumer which upon receiving a message goes and does some database updates. On some occasions the DB updates are quick but some require about a 60 sec. I have noticed that while the first message in still running, another message gets fired after 30 seconds?

Do you think adding in the config we resolve this?

receiverConfig.UseDelayedRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));

It seems this will only delay the redelivery rather than waiting to fire the message again.

I have added receiverConfig.UseDelayedRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));
hoping that message will have enough time to get processed and a duplicate message wont be fired.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the transport timing out and redelivering the message, vs anything in MassTransit causing the message to be redelivered. One minute was the default Lock Duration for Azure Service Bus, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chris, all the other queues which process data relatively faster, so my first thought was maybe I can extend the wait time for the message to be considered a fail and redeliver the message, Is there a way after the message has been sent, I can prolong the time to wait for message processing and then try to redeliver?

Comment: I forgot to mention that the second message is consumed by the other pod, We have two pods running for an app. Its never the same pod consuming the same message twice

Comment: Well, that's expected, RMQ is going to redeliver to the next available pod.